# How to implement font-awesome into a input appended through jQuery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I have a row that is created through jQuery via append, which contains a delete button.

**Desire Output:**

1. Instead of the word "delete" I would like to implement a font-awesome "fa-fa-trash" icon in the button.
2. What is the proper way to implement this?

```js
function dataTable(data) {
  var row = $('<tr id=' + data.id + '/>');
  $('#table').append(row);
  row.append($(
    '<td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" onclick="remove(' +
    data.id + ')"/></td>'));
}
```

Comment: i guess your datatable function works in some loop. To me you just have to know when to change to fa trash and when to danger. If i am understand wrong provide more detail of your problem otherwise not clear

Comment: Isn't it possible to have a fa-trash populate inside the bootstrap btn-danger?

Comment: oh you want to show icon inside bootstrap button? if thats true you have to put inside of that button. Not inside like in class <button><icon goes here></button> i all show you in answer

Comment: this will not work in jquery. hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here is my Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Munkhdelger/mavvtkve/)

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" >Submit<i class='fa fa-trash'></i></button>
```

```js
time = function datatable(data){

   table = $("table tbody tr");
    table.append(
    "<td><button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger' >Submit "+data+"<i class='fa fa-trash'></i></button> </td>"
    );
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="time('someid');" >append button to table bruh</button>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>first td without for visible</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: cause i removed your parameters

Comment: parameters which are the main reason why jquery is utilized.

Comment: This should do the job

Comment: Have you tried it? Because as with the answer provided above, it will just not populate the <td> at all. I don't think you can append button elements via jquery

Comment: ok i edited my jsfiddle reason why not working because jsfiddle online compile problem you should try it on your case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166932/discussion-between-munkhdelger-tumenbayar-and-t-c).

Answer (score 0):

You just change the input type submit to button

```
row.append('<td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="remove('+data.id+')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> delete</buton></td>');
```

Comment: This will not work. It just won't populate the <td> at all.

Comment: You cannot append a button element via jquery.